# Site loads with unwanted characters for guest users when "W3 Total Cache" is defined in wp-config.php

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache, question2answer

When a user is logged in, site loads without any problem but if a guest user visit the site, it shows some characters same as this:

> O-y²ee·¹”sÆlæ#u«lB,G«gÆ¯æÚå¿—TYûKä!E"¢ØÀÕìS<ðEùànú0"¸µq8ÜW1K™1ìµPóåÄ8D²ŠmmâP¦lËJzñC¥R#Íñ&À…¦Z0D"†˜y‘„¡«vb›‡l1yZ>ÑÊ¬nìÛÉ«âÅV7±³
>   W+Š

and nothing else shows

Im using Q2A with wordpress integrated

Q2A version: 1.6.3

Edit:

I reuploaded all Q2A files and nothing happened.

### ----------

I found that Q2A get in trouble when I define "W3 Total Cache" in wp-config.php

Comment: We can't help without a demo and the code

Comment: @DominicTobias I have a clone of both wordpress & Q2A on my local and works without any problem on localhost and I didn't change any codes.

Comment: Then try adding this to your `.htaccess` `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

Comment: Just changes characters to another! (...ߐ��&�t�2O��葖!��|�Q� �\�f�I�'���-F0yM�wP ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I thought problem was W3 Total Cache plugin.

disabling "Page Cache" in W3 Total Cache can solve this problem temporary.

I seeking for a better solution if possible.